# Make krunner wider

Tags: kde, plasma

A list of searched files like that displayed by Plasma's tool Krunner is more useful than a grid and helps to identify a file when the files searched and the search results are very numerous, have similar or long names or the same name but with different locations.

But when the path and other additional info is needed, those lines might not fit the krunner window, because it's too narrow.

How to make it wider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the launcher and pin its window from the dedicated button.

[image]

Press Alt-F3 (to open the window options), then select *More actions - Configure special window setting, Add Property*, and under "Size and position" select "Size".

(Instead of Alt-F3, one could also go to *System Settings>Windows Management>Window rules>Detect window properties* and click the krunner window.)

Something like this:

[image]

The changes are instant. On my laptop screen it gets almost full-screen when searching: the search field will stay the same, but the results will show the longer lines, like those of file and folder paths for example.

[image]